# Installing modules for Perl 6 using Panda but behind a proxy

Tags: git, raku

Seem to be lost on this one.

Anytime I do anything with panda, (update/install) I get the following error:

```
Could not download module metadata: Failed to connect: connection timed out.
Falling back to the curl command.
curl failed: The spawned process exited unsuccessfully (exit code: -16).
Falling back to the wget command.
wget failed as well: The spawned process exited unsuccessfully (exit code: -16). Sorry, have to give up.
  in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\61C4E003FB65304A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 138
  in any  at H:\.perl6\2016.01.1\precomp\34C40ED80206941C844106C0BECEBD0BCE0E58E3.1454618830.87862\61\61C4E003FB6530
4A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 1
  in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\61C4E003FB65304A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 134
  in any  at H:\.perl6\2016.01.1\precomp\34C40ED80206941C844106C0BECEBD0BCE0E58E3.1454618830.87862\61\61C4E003FB6530
4A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 1
  in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\61C4E003FB65304A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 128
  in any  at H:\.perl6\2016.01.1\precomp\34C40ED80206941C844106C0BECEBD0BCE0E58E3.1454618830.87862\61\61C4E003FB6530
4A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 1
  in method update at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\61C4E003FB65304A1A6771D177815A47C2333D7E line 94
  in sub MAIN at C:\rakudo\bin\panda line 43
  in block <unit> at C:\rakudo\bin\panda line 95
```

I found on this blog http://perl6maven.com/how-to-install-perl6-modules, someone in the comments having the same problem:

```
Gave it a shot, but I am behind a web proxy. So panda install Task::Star 
failed. OK, research and find that Http::UserAgent is needed. Go look for 
it, and the install instructions are "use panda install Http::UserAgent". 
Catch-22 time. Not encouraging at this point.

So I clone the Http::UserAgent from github and point panda to the local 
directory: git install ./http-useragent and still get connection timed out 
in retrieveing metadata. Any ideas?
```

So... Any Ideas?

Comment: The panda readme says "If you are behind a proxy, you need to [configure git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) and have HTTP::UserAgent installed which supports proxies." Have you configured git as per the link and cloned HTTP::UserAgent?

Comment: I have cloned HTTP::UserAgent but my perl6 compiler can't seem to find it. I've tried setting the PATH and PERL6LIB environment variables and still keep getting"===SORRY!===Could not find HTTP::UserAgent in:..."

Comment: What happens if you use the compiler option `-I` to point to the directory eg, if you're in the directory containing HTTP::UserAgent enter `perl6 -I. -e 'use HTTP::UserAgent'?

Comment: That allowed it to run but none of the commands would work for some reason. Looks like the installation was broken and I had to re-install. Didn't end up requiring `HTTP::UserAgent` after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright everyone and anyone, I think I've figured it out. And FYI I'm on windows so try and read between the lines for other OS's.

## I can't do anything with `panda`

If you are getting the above error message, that probably means you have run `panda update` too early. While almost every module tells you to run `panda update` before `panda install ...`.

## What do I do now?

You have to remove rakudo star and RE-INSTALL! I noticed after re-installing raduko, `panda list` started working again. I was ecstatic! The problem was that right after I ran `panda update` which resulted in the above error. Upon which I attempted to run `panda list` again, and to my surprise panda was now broken once again. So basically, re-install and **don't run `panda update`**.

## OK, now I'm back to where I started with not being able to connect to github

The stars have to align (*not really*) for you to be able to connect to github being behind a proxy. My solution involved a few things:

- Ensure you have the latest version of git installed (Otherwise it will complain)
- `git config http.proxy http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `git config https.proxy http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `git config --global https.proxy http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `git config http.sslVerify=false`
- `SET http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `SET https_proxy=http://user:password@proxy.website.com:port`
- `SET GIT_PROTOCOL=https`
- `SET GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`

Now obviously I have no idea what I'm doing and there are a large number of cross-over settings there but I'm pretty sure I had all of them set so it doesn't seem to hurt having more.

## SUCCESS!

So assuming you've gotten this far and you haven't used `panda update` yet, you should be able to install modules for perl6 using `panda install ...`!

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. Have you been on the freenode IRC channel #perl6? It would be good to link to this.

Comment: No Worries! No I haven't but feel free to do so. Turns out my company firewall won't let me on the IRC. Oh the irony...

Comment: https://perl6.slack.com/messages/general/? (http://perl6.bestforever.com/ for invite)